# Build a nested menu using python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, menu

I'm working on a GUI for a LCD screen connected to a Raspberry PI.

I'd like to build a menu from a dict like this :

```
my_menu = {
    "menu1": {
        "submenu1": {
            "subsubmenu1": None
        },
        "submenu2": None,
        "submenu3": None,
    },
    "menu2": {
        "submenu1": None,
        "submenu2": None,
    }
}

for item in my_menu:
    print(item)
}
```

I'd like to keep the same order as defined in the dictionary.

The problem is that python dictionaries are unordered and the menu items on the LCD screen are not displayed in the right order.

That way I could make it work easily in JS (using json) or PHP (using arrays), but I just start using python and I have no idea of the best way to do it in that language.

I have read some articles about OrderedDict but I'm not sure it's a good idea.

So my question is "how to do it in a clean and efficient way".

My code runs under python 2.7 but I can upgrade the version if necessary.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step into the ordered dict, then sort the submenus

```
from collections import OrderedDict

unsorted = {
    "menu2": {
        "submenu2": {
            "subsubmenu1": None
        },
        "submenu3": None,
        "submenu1": None,
    },
    "menu1": {
        "submenu3": None,
        "submenu1": None,
    }
}

ord_menu = OrderedDict(sorted(unsorted.items()))
for k,v in ord_menu.items():
    print(sorted(v))
    ord_menu[k] = sorted(v)
print(ord_menu)
```

if you're just trying to preserve order, just upgrade -from python 3.6 onward dict order is preserved, [from here.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !  I'll try it now and I'll let you know if it works as expected.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to sort the array alphabetically. My target is to keep the exact same order as defined in the dictionary. Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: if that is the case, then you don't even need an ordered dict. from Python 3.6, dicts preserve order by default. just upgrade from 2.7

Comment: Oh great !  I didn't know that. I'll try upgrading python

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Now everything is working perfectly. If you post an answer with your last comment, I can tag it as "accepted answer". Thanks again, you saved my day!